# Infinite product of $1-q^{n^2}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, partitions, theta-functions

Is there anything known about the following product? Is it a known function or related to a known function?
$$\prod_{n\geqslant1}(1-q^{n^2})$$

Comment: Well, it has an obvious combinatorial interpretation in terms of "partitions into squares"

Comment: @SamHopkins Yes indeed, this was in fact my original question. I do not know what is known about it.

Comment: Problem 3.28 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.08449 asks whether the coefficients of this power series are unbounded. I take this as evidence little is known about it.

Answer (score 3):

Write $\theta(q)=\sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} q^{n^2}$. Taking logarithms, we get that the logarithm of your function is

$\sum_n \ln(1-q^{n^2}) = -\sum_n \sum_m \frac 1 m q^{n^2m} = -\sum_m \frac 1 m \frac {\theta(q^m)-1} 2 = \frac 1 2 \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac {1 - \theta(q^m)} m$.

Answer (score 3):

Following up on Sam's comment, [A001156](https://oeis.org/A001156) in the OEIS gives the number of partitions of $n$ into squares; that generating function is the reciprocal of your product.  There's an equinumerous type of partitions given: partitions of $n$ where each part $k$ occurs a multiple of $k$ times (which contributes a multiple of $k^2$ to the weight).  You might look through the links and formula entries for the sequence to see if they lead to anything that interests you.

Comment: I tried Googling "pentagonal number theorem squares" and similar phrases and didn't get much that seemed relevant...

Comment: By the way, the coefficients of the OP's power series are also in the OEIS: http://oeis.org/A276516. Note that they are not always $0,\pm 1$!

Comment: @SamHopkins Far from it: the longer list shows that the 9996th entry is 18,786!

Comment: Yes; though as I commented above it is apparently unknown if the coefficients are unbounded.

Comment: @SamHopkins and BrianHopkins Many thanks for your help and for the references!

Answer (score 1):

Let $m$ be a positive integer. Let $f_{m}(z)=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}(1-z^{k^{m}})$. Then $f(z)$ is analytic in the disk $\{z:|z|<1\}$ and satisfies the following functional equation:

$$\prod_{j=1}^{\infty}f_{m}(z^{j^{m}})^{\mu(j)}=1.$$

Here $\mu$ denotes the Mobius Mu function which is defined by setting $\mu(M^{2}N)=0$ whenever $M,N$ are positive integers with $M>1$ and $\mu(p_{1}\dots p_{s})=(-1)^{s}$ whenever $p_{1},\dots,p_{s}$ are distinct primes.